# Is there a way to run function AFTER camera movements end? (MapBox)

Tags: flutter, mapbox

How can I run function after camera's movement ends e.g send API request.
I am using MapBox and  map controllers

Thanks!

Comment: welcome to stack overflow check here https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is [`moveend` event](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/map/#map.event:moveen).

```js
// Set an event listener that fires
// just after the map completes a transition.
map.on('moveend', function() {
console.log('A moveend event occurred.');
});
```

Comment: are we talking about flutter?

Comment: I’m talking about Mapbox camera, I guess the only camera you have in a mapbox integration